# List of buttons in swing

Tags: java, swing

I would like to implement a list of interactive buttons using Swing. It is something similar as on the picture (from NetBeans UI designer):

[image]

You can drag and drop the items to a canvas, or single click on the item and then single click on the canvas. However, I don't know which swing components I should use. Are that JList or JButtons or something different?

Comment: for NebBeans users is better look here http://netbeans.org/community/index.html

Comment: This is not a netBeans related question, the picture was only an example of the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There [is a tutorial avalaible](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-palette-api2.html) on how to achieve such functionality. It is utilizing the [NetBeans Palette API](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-spi-palette/overview-summary.html), which makes you dependent on NetBeans as Framework, not IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the goal, you might want to look into developing for the [NetBeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index_gl.html).